# Python Django threaded comments ordering

Tags: python, django

I am creating a django comments app.
I have created model Comments

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    path = models.CharField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list], max_length = 100, blank = True, editable = False)
    depth = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default = 0)
```

The way i store path tree is that:

1. First comment will have path [1].
2. Reply to first comment will have path [1,2]
3. Second comment will have path [3]
4. Second reply to first comment will have path [1,4].

And so on.
So something like this should happen.
[1]
[1,2]
[1,4]
[3]

I display it by fetching using the following line:

```
comment_list = Comments.objects.order_by('-path')
```

The problem is it displays newest comment first like this:
[3]
[1]
[1,4]
[1,2]
How do i correct it so that it prints oldest comment first?

Comment: You should probably use something like [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/index.html) rather than constructing your own path implementation.

Comment: If you don't implement django-mptt, you need to sort each path as a tree, not alphabetically as will be the default for a CharField. How you do that, I'm not sure.